# Image opening intent defaults to Google Drive

Tags: android

I am aware that this may not be strictly an issue of programming (especially since the problem is not reproducible on all devices, see below). However, any insight would be very helpful.

I currently use the following code for launching an Intent allowing the user to select an image from a legitimate source:

```
public void onLoad() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Snap"), SELECT_ACTION);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_4dot4_ACTION);
    }
}
```

Running this code on a Galaxy S3 works fine - I can freely select whether to get the image from Gallery, Google Drive etc. However, running the exact same code on a Galaxy S4 defaults to using Google Drive with no other options. All Default App settings have been reset on both devices prior to testing.

Could this be an SDK issue, and if so how can it be addressed?